# How to open leaf shutter on Mamiya RZ67 lens?

Tags: mamiya

For some reason the leaf shutter on the 110mm lens on my Mamiya RZ67 seems to be stuck closed and refuses to open.

First time using this camera so I'm bound to have done something wrong... Any advice??

Answer (score 4):

The following is from the Mamiya RZ67 User Manual and may help in determining why the Shutter will not release

**When the shutter can not be released**

1. Has the film been completely advanced to the first frame? Have all the exposures already been made (10 with 120, 20 with 220)?
2. Has the Cocking Lever been advanced as far as it will go?
3. Has the Dark Slide been removed?
4. Have you locked the Shutter Release Button and forgotten?
5. Is there a battery in the Battery Chamber? Is the battery still good?
6. Is the "T" lever of the lens on "N"?
7. Is the camera speed dial on RBL and a RZ lens is on camera?
8. Is the camera speed dial on AEF and the AE Finder and a RZ lens is not
   attached?
9. Have you used the mirror -up mode and red ring on the collar is still visible after removing the cable release?

• In the case of examples 1-3, an orange lamp will illuminate in the viewfinder if an error has been made.